# how to cache file content with angular translate (cookie storage)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is there a way in angular translate to cache the file content
(I've just googled but with no lucky)
so I don't need to load it from the server ?

Comment: generally the max size of a cookies is 4096 bytes

Comment: You can cache your view templates however as for the actual translation files themselves, due to the size of them you'll probably want to retrieve them rather than caching